# How to remove line between widgets and center other widget?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, line

I have one issue that cant resolve. I want to remove line that is between other two widgets in [my site](http://raion.asia/), and centralize the other 2 contact widgets. How to make this? The CSS from that widget that i want to remove is :

```
.footer-branding {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;      
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 30px 15px 15px;
}
```

Image where is shown what line I want to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding some css for that:

```
.footer-branding {
    width:0;
    padding:0;
}
.footer-contact {
    broder-left:0; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad to help you :)